# Which tool can open merge module file to check?

Tags: .net, installation, windows-installer, setup-deployment

I have some merge module files *.msm. I am wondering if there is any tool to open those files to check.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These files are used for building MSI package, based on Windows Installer technology. You can use Orca.exe tool, available for free, or SuperOrca. The content of the file is similar to a database, organized on tables.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa243932(v=vs.60).aspx